# Does 50-80kb of CSS matter?

Tags: css, filesize

I was looking at a CSS file for a low traffic website which used a framework which partially lead it to have a CSS file size of 113kb.

Just for example sake I cut the code in half so it had around 1622 (originally around 3244) lines of CSS (roughly 50% reduction).

My question is does with an additional 50-80kb CSS file matter these days for low end use websites, say under 10,000 visitors a month?

Comment: it may affect your website performance .
you can minify  the css code thus reduce the size of file.

Comment: Not really because most of it is cached anyway so re-visits won't be re-downloading all your CSS files from your server. 10,000 visitors a month to grab 50 to 80kb is nothing for modern internet speeds. If you do start to see performance issues, consider minimizing it but you will usually find performance issues are not coming from people loading CSS.

Comment: Thanks @Dave that helps clarify it, so no big need to panic on such a size. And thanks 3gth in regards to minify.

Comment: if it's not running https, it slows down first load of website, because of the way the page is downloaded, so every kb counts on initial load..